# Is is possible to trigger 'Container Loaded' twice or force GTM to reload ? (React)

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, react-gtm-module

I am actually working on a large web application, which was initially built with Symfony/Twig, and that is gradually refactored using React. But since I am using React, some of my pages get no "views" in Google Tag Manager (GTM).

I followed [this guide](https://measureschool.com/track-single-page-applications-gtm/) to use GTM in React. But I have a lot (tens) of Tags and Triggers in GTM, based on the 3 native events "Container loaded" (`gtm.js`), "DOM Ready" (`gtm.dom`) and "Window Loaded" (`gtm.load`).

The first solution (from the guide) is to add a new custom trigger (based on History Source) and link our tags on this new trigger. But since I have too many tags, this is not a satisfying solution.

The second solution is to manually trigger events, using the datalayer. This works fine, I can easily trigger the "DOM Ready" and "Window Loaded" events. But it does not work as expected for "Container Loaded". I guess that GTM does not handle this event more than once per page load.

### So, here are my questions:

- Is it possible to "fake a reload" in GTM (so that GTM act like if I opened a new page)?
- Or is it possible to trigger "Container Loaded" (`gtm.js`) multiple times?

### Screenshot of a "normal" Container Loaded trigger:

[image: screenshot gtm]

### Screenshot of a manually called Container Loaded trigger (from React):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. You can call `gtm.dom` or `gtm.load` more than once but not `gtm.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the dataLayer if you switch from page to page in your SPA. Which should simulate something like a fake reload. Also, it's best practice to use VirtualPageViews to track your website.